# R subtract value based on category and date the tidyverse-way

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm new to stackoverflow, but not new to R. However I'm running into some trouble while subtracting some values from a tibble. I created a small example, which shows the setup and my attempt (so far):

```
library(tidyverse)
fruit<-tibble(date=rep(seq.Date(as.Date('2020-03-01'),
                                as.Date('2020-03-04'),
                                by='day'),3),
              cat=c(rep('apple',4),
                    rep('peach',4),
                    rep('strawberry', 4)),
              value=1:12)


bananas<-tibble(date=rev(seq.Date(as.Date('2020-03-01'),
                            as.Date('2020-03-04'),
                            by='day')),
              cat=rep('bananas', 4),
              value= 4:1)

mutate(fruit, 
       value = ifelse(cat=='apple' & date %in% bananas$date,
                                    value-bananas$value, value))
```

I know, that my `cat=='apple' & date %in% bananas$date` construction normally shouldn't work either. However I can't really figure out how to subset the larger tibble, an then vectorized match the dates in order to subtract the right values from each other and then return the entire larger tibble again.

A simple workaround would be to create a unique "helper ID" by pasting category and date together, but I think there should be an easier way.

I hope the issue becomes clear - I would be happy for any hint.

Best,

Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you mean something like this :

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(fruit, bananas, by = 'date') %>%
   mutate(value = ifelse(cat.x == 'apple', value.x - value.y, value.x))


# A tibble: 12 x 6
#   date       cat.x      value.x cat.y   value.y value
#   <date>     <chr>        <int> <chr>     <int> <int>
# 1 2020-03-01 apple            1 bananas       1     0
# 2 2020-03-02 apple            2 bananas       2     0
# 3 2020-03-03 apple            3 bananas       3     0
# 4 2020-03-04 apple            4 bananas       4     0
# 5 2020-03-01 peach            5 bananas       1     5
# 6 2020-03-02 peach            6 bananas       2     6
# 7 2020-03-03 peach            7 bananas       3     7
# 8 2020-03-04 peach            8 bananas       4     8
# 9 2020-03-01 strawberry       9 bananas       1     9
#10 2020-03-02 strawberry      10 bananas       2    10
#11 2020-03-03 strawberry      11 bananas       3    11
#12 2020-03-04 strawberry      12 bananas       4    12
```

We join `fruit` and `bananas` by `date` so that date matches and then subtract `value` from `banana` only if `cat` is `"apple"`. You can then `select` the columns that you need.

Answer (score 1):

exactly - thank you very much!

Here the entire thing (also including appending "bananas" to the fruits)

```
left_join(fruit, bananas, by = 'date') %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(cat.x == 'apple', value.x - value.y, value.x))%>%
  select(-c(value.x, cat.y, value.y))%>%
  rename(cat=cat.x)%>%bind_rows(arrange(bananas, date))
```